# How to make AHK click arrowkeys based on symbols displayed on screen?

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

I play a game where the clicking arrowkeys corresponding to the arrow image on the screen will increase my player's stats. How can I possibly make AHK "read" the arrow symbol and click the corresponding arrowkey by itself? I'm fairly new to AHK so please excuse me if this is a bad question.

Comment: By "reading" the arrow symbol, do you mean the AHK to process the image to classify it as up/down or something else ?

Comment: yes. for example, if the image was an arrow pointing left, i'd want AHK to click the left arrow key. also if there were multiple arrows in a horizontal row, i'd want it to click the arrows on the keyboard based on what arrows are on the screen from left to right. something like that.

Comment: Well, AHK has `imageSearch` method which can search an image file on the screen and locate it. However, I doubt that for the arrow images it can classify it. You might need to use something more extensive for the image classification part. Have a look at the method in here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
#NoEnv

Numpad1::
Settimer, findimage, 2000
return

Numpad3::
Settimer, findimage, Off
return

findimage:
ImageSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, %A_ScriptDir%\img\arrow.png
MouseClick, left, %X%, %Y%
return
```

Comment: you just need to put a picture into a folder called "img" in the same directory where your ahk script is. let me know if u have any questions about it.